# Laravel 5.4 back() method redirects too many times

Tags: laravel

Browser shows me too many redirects when I use back() helper method.
I have seen many solutions but no one is provided clear solution.

Here is my code.

authentication middleware contains....

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()) 
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    return back();
}
```

On kernel.php add this middleware....

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
           'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
           'auth.basic'=>\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
           'bindings'=>\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
           'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
           'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
           'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
           'authenticate' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware::class,
       ];
```

A controller called userController uses this middleware in constructor...

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('authenticate');
}
```

Here is routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index');
Route::get('/cpanel','UsersController@dashboard');

Route::group(['prefix'=>'cpanel'],function() {

  Route::get('/settings','UsersController@settings');
  Route::post('/settings','UsersController@storeSettings');
  Route::get('/post/create',function() {
    return view('posts.newpost');
  })->name('createpost');
  Route::post('/post/create','PostsController@create');
  Route::get('/posts','PostsController@posts');
  Route::delete('/post/delete/{id}','PostsController@delete');

});
```

And finally postsController method...

```
public function index()
{
      $posts = Post::all();
      return view('index',['posts'=>$posts]);
}
```

But when I type domain/cpanel it shows redirects too many times. I don't understand why.

Comment: paste content of **UsersController@dashboard**

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to redirect in some cases and prevent redirects too many time from the back method, you can do this:

```
<?php
   if(request()->fullUrl() === redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl()){
      return redirect('/');
   }

   return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 0):

your **authenticate** middleware cause a loop in some situation like there's no previous visit. Instead, you can for example change `return back();` to `return redirect()->url('/')` or ignore some method when applying middleware in **__constructor()**

and if you forget, there is **auth** middleware.

Comment: auth middleware return back to /login but i want users return rack to previous url.

Comment: replace Route::get('/cpanel','UsersController@dashboard'); to Route::get('/','UsersController@dashboard'); then move it inside **cpanel** group prefix

Comment: **bs.** if you write in browser **example.com/cpanel** and of course you are not login you will make a loop situation cause there isn't a previous URL to move to.